# Stack ggplot plot not displaying correctly R

Tags: r

If been trying to make a stack barplot with the ggplot2 package but when I launch the plot the result is not as I expected to be.

```
nombres <- c("Hotel", "Año", "Ingresos")

hoteles <- data.frame(
                hc1 = c("Hawaiian Club",1993,450000),
                hc2 = c("Hawaiian Club",1994,475000),
                hc3 = c("Hawaiian Club",1995,390000),
                fr1 = c("French Riviera",1993,225000),
                fr2 = c("French Riviera",1994,240000),
                fr3 = c("French Riviera",1995,205000),
                bb1 = c("Bahamas Beach",1993,245000),
                bb2 = c("Bahamas Beach",1994,255000),
                bb3 = c("Bahamas Beach",1995,345000),
                row.names = nombres)

hoteles <- data.frame(t(hoteles))

ggplot(hoteles, aes(fill=Año, y=Ingresos, x=Hotel)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

The result is the following one:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XzZU.png)

Any clue? The y ads is not displaying correctly the income of the hotels ! Thank you in advance

Comment: Your `Ingresos` variable is `character`, transform it to `numeric`:  `ggplot(hoteles, aes(fill=Año, y=as.numeric(Ingresos), x=Hotel)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")`

Comment: Better yet, don't build your data that way, R "punishes" you for doing it that way. You might find `tibble::tribble` to be an aesthetically similar way to build it, but frankly `read.csv(text='Hotel,Año,Ingresos\n"Hawaiian Club",1993,450000\n"Hawaiian Club",1994,47500')` also works (and you can use real newlines in place of `\n` there).

Comment: thank u to both of you, it is workin now ! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Ingersos" are read by R as characters (because of the way you input the data).
You can fix that by adding [as.numeric](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/numeric):

`hoteles$Ingresos = as.numeric(hoteles$Ingresos)`

## In your code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

nombres <- c("Hotel", "Año", "Ingresos")

hoteles <- data.frame(
  hc1 = c("Hawaiian Club",1993,450000),
  hc2 = c("Hawaiian Club",1994,475000),
  hc3 = c("Hawaiian Club",1995,390000),
  fr1 = c("French Riviera",1993,225000),
  fr2 = c("French Riviera",1994,240000),
  fr3 = c("French Riviera",1995,205000),
  bb1 = c("Bahamas Beach",1993,245000),
  bb2 = c("Bahamas Beach",1994,255000),
  bb3 = c("Bahamas Beach",1995,345000),
  row.names = nombres)



hoteles <- data.frame(t(hoteles))

### THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO ADD!
hoteles$Ingresos = as.numeric(hoteles$Ingresos)
###

ggplot(hoteles, aes(fill=Año, y=Ingresos, x=Hotel)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

## Output:

[image: Stacked Barplot]

Comment: That's it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Up front: fix the problem as early in the process as possible.

Ultimately, you are seeing a symptom (side-effect) of a data-import problem. That is, after your code, you may notice that

```r
str(hoteles)
# 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Hotel   : chr  "Hawaiian Club" "Hawaiian Club" "Hawaiian Club" "French Riviera" ...
#  $ Año     : chr  "1993" "1994" "1995" "1993" ...
#  $ Ingresos: chr  "450000" "475000" "390000" "225000" ...
```

telling you that all columns are strings, despite the intuitive expectation that `Año` and `Ingresos` should be numeric or integer.

While the other answer (based on TarJae's comment) fixes the issue post-import, you should look to define the data the right way the first time. I'm going on the premise that you are storing it like that because you are building it in a source `.R` file somewhere, and not receiving a CSV file.

Alternatives, with that assumption:

```r
hoteles <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Hotel          , ~Año, ~Ingresos
  , "Hawaiian Club" , 1993,    450000
  , "Hawaiian Club" , 1994,    475000
  , "Hawaiian Club" , 1995,    390000
  , "French Riviera", 1993,    225000
  , "French Riviera", 1994,    240000
  , "French Riviera", 1995,    205000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , 1993,    245000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , 1994,    255000
  , "Bahamas Beach" , 1995,    345000
)

hoteles <- read.csv(text = '
Hotel,Año,Ingresos
"Hawaiian Club" , 1993,    450000
"Hawaiian Club" , 1994,    475000
"Hawaiian Club" , 1995,    390000
"French Riviera", 1993,    225000
"French Riviera", 1994,    240000
"French Riviera", 1995,    205000
"Bahamas Beach" , 1993,    245000
"Bahamas Beach" , 1994,    255000
"Bahamas Beach" , 1995,    345000
',strip.white = TRUE)
```

(The embedded double-quotes are not even required, assuming you have no embedded commas.)